# How do I clean up vi and reinstall it completely?

Tags: python, vi

Basically when I try to run `vi`, I have the following error (and after open it, there are a lot of errors):

```
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#bootstrap#Bootstrap:
line   35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.snippet_manager import SnippetManager
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet_manager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.snippet.definition import UltiSnipsSnippetDefinition
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet/definition/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.snippet.definition.ultisnips import UltiSnipsSnippetDefinition
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet/definition/ultisnips.py", line 6, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.snippet.definition._base import SnippetDefinition
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet/definition/_base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.text_objects import SnippetInstance
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/text_objects/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.text_objects._shell_code import ShellCode
  File "/Users/myname/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/text_objects/_shell_code.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Basically, I want to reinstall `vi`. 
However, after following the instructions:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html
http://www.vim.org/git.php

I still have this error. What should I do?

In my memory I once have accidentally deleted `/usr/local/bin`...
not sure if that affects...

Comment: Looks to me like you're using homebrew, [does this link help?](http://rkulla.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-path-to-homebrew.html). This is from googling "/usr/local/Cellar" which I'd never heard of before.  Perhaps your python is backlevel? I don't know.

Comment: I doubt you need to reinstall vi completely, what you should start by doing is stopping it loading your ~/.vimrc and the contents of ~/.vim. Do this by creating a save directory and `cd ~; mkdir vimsaved; mv .vimrc .vim vimsaved`. You should also improve details of your Q by telling us your OS and version of vim

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the installation,  it's in your plugins or python installation.

Remove /Users/myname/.vim/bundle, maybe the whole /Users/myname/.vim/  and try again.

BTW I guess you are not really talking about vi, but vim.